# Simple search not working on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I might be missing something here. I am following rails casts here.

I have model called **Production** with a `name` column.

In my controller I added a new method for searching as follows:

**productions_controller.rb**

```
  def index
   @productions =Production.all
  end

  def search
    if params[:search]
      @productions = Production.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
  end
```

And then I added this action in route file:

```
resources :productions do
    collection do
        get 'search'
    end
  end
```

I gave a search field in **index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag productions_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And then I created a landing for search action

**search.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Director</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @productions.each do |production| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= production.name %></td>
        <td><%= production.director %></td>
        <td><%= production.status %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', production %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_production_path(production) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', production, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**productions table**

```
create_table "productions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "director"
    t.integer "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now when I search for a keyword in the name table I am getting all the names in the table, even which are no close to the keyword entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Rails 2.3 query syntax, this rails cast is terribly outdated. It should be more like:

```
@productions = Production.where('productions.name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Also, you have it in `search` action, while you should put this code in `index` action, since the search form routes to `index`.

If you want it to stay in `search` action, you should change your form path:

```
 <%= form_tag [:search, :productions], :method => 'get' do %>
```

Comment: I added this in index action like you suggested. Now even thought I have a column  called `name` in **productions** I am getting this error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: production.name: SELECT "productions".* FROM "productions" WHERE (production.name like '%avatar%')`

Comment: @user3576036 sorry, my mistake, your table name is in plural, `productions`. Try it now.

Comment: This is working. But instead of index method I want it in a separate method. That's why I created a new method called `search` and added it to routes. Why is it not working with `search` method ? And how can I make it work from `search` method instead of `index` method ?

Comment: @user3576036 I edited my answer to reflect your needs.